# Web app persistent authentication with Facebook

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a web app that has a ~ Log In with Facebook ~ button that is implemented with the PHP SDK. It works as usual. Users get redirected to Facebook. Facebook redirects them back to the web app. The web app gets their information and creates a DB record about them.

The problem is that these logins are not persistent. The next time the same user opens up the web app, it won't recognise them.

How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches:

1. Use a remember me cookie similar to a normal form login. To increase security measures you might want to perform a check with Facebook API if the user is the same:

   1. Relate the Facebook OAuth token and the "remember me" cookie token in your database.
   2. When a user creates a new session with a "remember me cookie" you could check (with client-side code) if the corresponding Facebook token is valid and the user is still logged in with your app.
2. Store only the Facebook token client-side (Local storage). On subsequent sessions you could check who the user is via the Facebook API and the stored token. This approach is slower though.

---

In any case you would want to *exchange the short-lived Facebook access token for a long-lived access token*<sup>1</sup> and store that in your database.

Read more on access tokens<sup>2</sup>:

1: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending
2: https://www.sammyk.me/access-token-handling-best-practices-in-facebook-php-sdk-v4